# Search operation with marklogic database using .net core

Tags: .net, marklogic

How can I search and retrieve data from the MarkLogic database using a .NET application?

Suppose inside MarkLogic is a document with the URI `/dotnet/page.json` and JSON data like

```
{ "Name":"John","Area":"AAA", "code":"3" }
```

I want to search for that data using .NET to fetch all the data where the `code` `3` is present. Maybe from a specific document or collection. Any solution will be helpful with .NET.

Comment: For .net, you'll probably use REST https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev

Comment: When i am trying to call inside .net using /v1/search it's giving me the total occurrence and in which document it is present. Are there any specific code example present where i can fetch data from document based upon passing search data and it will call like 'POST' or 'GET'  http call inside .net.

Answer (score 2):

MarkLogic provides APIs for Java and Node.js, but there isn't one specifically for .NET. That said, you can talk to MarkLogic with any language that can send HTTP requests, by using the REST API, as noted by Michael Gardner. To do a search like the one you described, you could send a [GET request to /v1/search](http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/search).

Besides the documentation, MarkLogic University provides free live and on-demand training. I encourage you to take a look at the [developer track](https://www.marklogic.com/learn/university/developer-track/).

Comment: There is, however, a community API for invoking Data Service endpoints on MarkLogic. See https://www.nuget.org/packages/MarkLogic.Client/

Comment: When i am trying to call inside .net using /v1/search it's giving me the total occurrence and in which document it is present. Are there any specific code example present where i can fetch data from document based upon passing search data.

Comment: You can configure /v1/search to return entire documents(transform-results: raw https://docs.marklogic.com/10.0/guide/search-dev/appendixa#id_50098) . If you only wanted to get one document, you could set page size to one. Wanting to get data based on search criteria is inherently a search function, so it's to be expected that the response wants to give you multiple results.